# react-native 0.68 vs SFMCSDK 7

Tags: marketing-cloud, react-native

I've recently been integrating the `react-native-marketingcloudsdk` into an app, during this time we've upgraded to react-native 0.68 which targets Android 12. Now that I'm ready to add the sdk changes and rebased, I've found that Android builds crash on startup with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: our.app.package: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.a(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.b.c(Unknown Source:40)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.c.c$2.a(Unknown Source:189)
    at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.e.g.run(Unknown Source:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

It seems like v7 of the marketing cloud sdk doesn't support Android 12, but there isn't a version of `react-native-marketingcloudsdk` that uses v8. We want to stay as up to date as possible with react-native (updating through several versions is not fun), but we've also made a commitment to rolling MobilePush so I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Other than rolling my own library that uses marketingcloud v8 is there any advice on how I should proceed?

Comment: Correct. To date, only version 8 of the SDK supports Android 12. Please open a voice of customer request through your account executive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An updated version 7 of the Android Push SDK has been released with Android 12 support. The React Native plugin has been updated to use this new version of the MC Push SDK.